# How to use use polymorphic associations across namespaced models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, refinerycms

I understand how you can use the class_name option in active directory to refer to namespaces models:

```
has_one :slide, :class_name => '::Refinery::Slides::Slide'
```

And how to use polymorphic associations

```
has_one :slide, :as => :slideable
```

Can you use them together?

```
has_one :slide, :class_name => '::Refinery::Slides::Slide', :as => :slideable
```

And if so, how do you define the polymorphic association?

```
belongs_to :slideable, :polymorphic => true, class_name='::Refinery::Slideables::Slideable' #NO
```

I'm working with RefineryCMS and every engine you add gets namespaced in Refinery::PluralModel::SingularModel.  Basically, I want to be able to associate a slide with either a case study or a job. Here are the actual models.

```
module Refinery
  module CaseStudies
    class CaseStudy < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      attr_accessible :title, :description, :position
      has_one :slide, :class_name => '::Refinery::Slides::Slide', :as => :slideable
    end
  end
end

module Refinery
  module Works
    class Work < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      attr_accessible :title, :description, :position, 
      has_one :slide, :class_name => '::Refinery::Slides::Slide', :as => :slideable
    end
  end
end

module Refinery
  module Slides
    class Slide < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      attr_accessible :slide_id, :caption, :position, :slideable_id, :slideable
      belongs_to :slide, :class_name => '::Refinery::Image'
      belongs_to :slideable, :polymorphic => true
    end
  end
end
```

It seems like I should be able to say slide.slideable.title but I get an error:
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

[apidoc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) specifies that inverse_of cannot be used with polymorphic, but says nothing about class_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a polymorphic association work, you need to add a type column along with an id column on the model that 'belongs_to' another. The type column will store the class name so there's no need to specify in the generic association.

For example, a `Comment` can belong to a `Question` or an `Answer`. Let's call questions and answers "commentable". A comment should have columns for `:commentable_id` and `:commentable_type`.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has columns :commentable_id and :commentable_type
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

# example
comment = Comment.new(:body => "Nice answer!")
comment.commentable = Answer.find(1)
comment.save
```

So, in your case, you can remove the `:class_name` options from `Work` and `CaseStudy` and make sure you add the columns `:slide_type` (to go with `:slide_id`) and `:slideable_type` (to go with `:slideable_id`) to your `Slide`. It should all "just work" with namespaced class names.

```
module Refinery
  module CaseStudies
    class CaseStudy < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      attr_accessible :title, :description, :position
      has_one :slide, :as => :slideable
    end
  end
end

module Refinery
  module Works
    class Work < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      attr_accessible :title, :description, :position, 
      has_one :slide, :as => :slideable
    end
  end
end

module Refinery
  module Slides
    class Slide < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      attr_accessible :slide_id, :caption, :position, :slideable_id, :slideable
      # add :slide_type and :slideable_type columns
      belongs_to :slide, :polymorphic => true
      belongs_to :slideable, :polymorphic => true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for such a thorough answer!  I'm skeptical about being able to remove class_name but here goes - will come back and let you know.

Comment: it looks like you are right, i can remove the class_name because in my form I'm setting the slideable_type like this
slide.radio_button(:slideable_type, Refinery::Works::Work, :checked => (:slideable_type == 'works'))